# How to pin information to the top of a terminal window on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, terminal, fish

I've seen demos where folks have had a Mac OSX terminal where the current time + username + directory are afixed (like 'freeze rows' in excel) to the top of the terminal window (not in the title bar), offering all the friendly context info I need while leaving lots of room for the command prompt after a simple '$'.

How do I tweak my Terminal to look like that?

PS. If it matters, I have recently started using an alternative shell called fish: http://fishshell.com/ but I'm happy with any answer for any shell.

EDIT: I went off to find the demo which first placed this idea in my head and I actually FOUND IT: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBt2g9ekiug#t=55

Comment: What does that youtube link have to do with your question?

Comment: It takes you to the exact spot in the video where the presenter is using Mac OSX terminal with some information pinned to the top.  This is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Edit 2:

Add these lines to your ~/.zshrc:

```
case $TERM in
  xterm*)
    precmd () {print -Pn "e]0;%~a"}
    ;;
esac
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you are using bash:

```
case $TERM in
  xterm*)
    PS1="[e]0;wa]\$ "
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
    ;;
esac
```

Have a look at [this link](http://mindthecode.com/customize-the-terminal/). I think you'll enjoy it :)

Edit: another good [link](http://www.stevendobbelaere.be/installing-and-configuring-the-oh-my-zsh-shell/)

Comment: Thanks for the advise. I'll review it and filter the content in a couple of hours

Comment: Thanks for the links @oski but its not _quite_ what I'm looking for.  In fact, the first link is almost exactly what I'm using right now, only with fish shell this is one of the prebuilt prompt options available from the web-based [fish_config](http://fishshell.com/assets/img/screenshots/web_config.png). I just now went out and found the demo that I was thinking of and will add it to the question text to make it more clear.